# How to put User Profile in a Block?

Tags: users

I know this is simple but can't find the answer. I'm just wanting to put the contents of  user-profile.tpl.php in a block. No extra formatting or anything. Just pull the information and put it in a block. It can either be in my custom module or by creating a block. Thanks for your help!

After trying the initial suggestion, I received this error message:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types user.module
```

My user-profile.tpl.php doesn't contain the usual information and I should have mentioned that originally. There's a lot to it but I think the problem is here:

```
$account = menu_get_object('user');
```

Since it calls that immediately at the top, it may create a problem. Beyond that, the rest of the user-profile.tpl.php file uses the account variable highlighted above to get a bunch more information.

I'm using the latest version of Drupal which is 7.7 at this time.

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 6 you create a custom block and let the content be:

```
theme('user_profile', $account);
```

For Drupal 7 you do change the code a bit:

```
render(user_view($account));
```

In both cases `$account` if the fully loaded user object who's profile you want to display in the block.

Comment: Thanks @googletorp, that definitely answers the question in most cases. Unfortunately, I'm seeing an error message: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/XXXX/public_html/modules/user/user.module on line 2534

Comment: @Bradon: Update your question with more info. What version are you using, what does your code look like.