# How do you create a block that contains fields from the User Profile?

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I tried using the method described in one of the answers here: [How to put user profile in a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/how-to-put-user-profile-in-a-block)

I created a block and used the following PHP code as a test; 
`<?php render(user_view($account)); ?>`

It didnt work. So the question remains, How can you create a block and call user profile fields into it using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7) only returns the string, it doesn't print it to the output. This code should work:

```
<?php print render(user_view($account)); ?>
```

Assuming of course that you have loaded the `$account` object. If not you probably want to use something like:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
```

As an aside, using the PHP filter is considered bad practice (it uses `eval()` which is an inherent security risk).

The best way to get what you're looking for is to write a small custom module that implements [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [`hook_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7):

```
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  return array(
    'user_profile' => array(
      'info' => 'User Profile Block',
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
    )
  );
}

function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  if ($delta == 'user_profile') {
    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
    $block['subject'] = 'User Profile';
    $block['content'] = user_view($account);
  }

  return $block;
}
```

If your new to writing modules the best resource I know of is the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), and in particular the [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112) sub-section; it will walk you through all of the steps necessary to get your module up and running.

**UPDATE**

Just to address your second comment...

I think the easiest way to get only certain fields to display would be to install the [Entity View Modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module. Then you can create a custom view mode for the user entity (called `block_profile` or something), and in the "Manage Fields" admin page for users assign only the fields you want to be displayed to that new view mode.

Then you can pass the new view mode to the `user_view()` function:

```
$block['content'] = user_view($account, 'block_profile');
```

And voila, your block will contain only the fields that you've added to the new view mode through the admin UI.

If Entity View Modes is causing you issues you can just uninstall it, and add the new view mode yourself using [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) (again in your new custom module):

```
function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['user']['view modes']['profile_block'] = array(
    'label' => t('Profile Block'), 
    'custom settings' => TRUE
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you! Can you elaborate a bit more on the 'module creation' process? Or, add a link to tutorial? Then this answer would be 100% solid.

Comment: Also, I see this line: $block['content'] = user_view($account); And cant help but wonder if it would be possible to specify fields instead of the entire profile?

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit; rendering certain fields requires a bit more effort but it's relatively easy. Hope it helps :)

Comment: When trying to use the Entity View Modes, I got the following error; Notice: Undefined index: #bundle in ds_build_load(). I know that it has nothing to do with the Entity View Mode module as its an error with DS. I will go about create the module for the user profile block. Once I finish with that I will post an update.

Comment: I've added a bit more...if that module is causing you problems you can add the view mode through code pretty easily. As you're already writing a module this might even be preferable to having another contrib module installed

Comment: clive, I can't thank you enough for the help. I've decided that am going to modify the 'author pane' module since its pretty close to what I want/need. It already gives me all the profile fields by using the $account array. Is this something that goes against a "Best practice" or causes a potential for security issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the user profile using:

```
<?php print render($user_profile); ?>
```

You can get specific user information by

```
<?php print render($user_profile['user_picture']); ?> 
<?php print render($user_profile['summary']); ?>
```

Comment: I tried <?php print render($user_profile); ?>. It gave me a blank block. I tried using print_r($user_profile) to check if anything was loaded and I get an error: Notice: Undefined variable: user_profile in eval().

Comment: Sorry, the above code would only work at the theme level.